# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a little HTML/CSS/JS program that interpolates between color values. I have two inputs that take CSS hex colors, and then I would like to use these values in the JavaScript code. I'm getting the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`  and I am not sure how to bind the  to my javaScript function. Any input would be appreciated.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/jon424/pen/mdRbbYQ?editors=1111

```js
function getColorValues(color1, color2) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let firstColor = hexToRgbA(color1);
  let secondColor = hexToRgbA(color2);
  console.log('first: ' + firstColor + ' second: ' + secondColor);
  return [firstColor, secondColor];
}

const [firstColor, secondColor] = getColorValues();

function hexToRgbA(hex) {
  var c;
  if (/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)) {
    c = hex.substring(1).split('');
    if (c.length == 3) {
      c = [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
    }
    c = '0x' + c.join('');
    return [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',');
  }
  throw new Error('Bad Hex');
}

const GColor = function(r, g, b) {
  r = (typeof r === 'undefined') ? 0 : r;
  g = (typeof g === 'undefined') ? 0 : g;
  b = (typeof b === 'undefined') ? 0 : b;
  return {
    r: r,
    g: g,
    b: b
  };
};
const createColorRange = function(c1, c2) {
  let colorList = [],
    tmpColor;
  for (let i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    tmpColor = new GColor();
    tmpColor.r = c1.r + ((i * (c2.r - c1.r)) / 255);
    tmpColor.g = c1.g + ((i * (c2.g - c1.g)) / 255);
    tmpColor.b = c1.b + ((i * (c2.b - c1.b)) / 255);
    colorList.push(tmpColor);
  }
  const b = colorList.slice().reverse();
  let final = colorList.concat(b)
  return final;
}

const colorOne = new GColor(firstColor);
const colorTwo = new GColor(secondColor);
const range = createColorRange(colorOne, colorTwo);
let pointer = 0;

function rotateColors() {
  const currentColor = range[pointer];
  document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + currentColor.r + "," + currentColor.g + "," + currentColor.b + ")";
  pointer++;
  if (pointer < range.length) {
    window.setTimeout(rotateColors, 5);
  } else if (pointer === range.length) {
    pointer = 0;
    window.setTimeout(rotateColors, 5);
  }
}

rotateColors();
```

```css
#test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="color1">Color One:</label>
  <input type="text" id="color1" name="fname">
  <br><br>
  <label for="color2">Color Two:</label>
  <input type="text" id="color2" name "color2"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getColorValues(document.getElementById('color1').value, document.getElementById('color2').value)" />
</form>
<br><br>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: `const [firstColor, secondColor] = getColorValues();` is not called when there's a click or an event, so there's no `window.event` to stop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can figure you are trying to accomplish the following result. The initial issue `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined` is easily resolved by passing the `event` as an argument to the `getColorValues` function. With that function streamlined a little I discovered other issues whilst testing and have put the odd comment here and there below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

    let c1=document.forms.colours.color1;
    let c2=document.forms.colours.color2;
    let div=document.getElementById("test");
    let pointer=0;
    let range=[];
    
    let tx=NaN; // keep a record of the timer so it can be cancelled before starting a new one
    
    const getColorValues=(e)=>{
        /*
            You need to pass the event as an argument to the method if you wish to use `preventDefault
            Alternatively set the submit button as a regular button.
        */
        e.preventDefault();
        return [ hexToRgb( c1.value ), hexToRgb( c2.value ) ];
    };
    
    const hexToRgb=(hex)=>{
        let c;
        if(/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test( hex ) ){
            c= hex.substring(1).split('');
            if( c.length==3 ) c=[ c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2] ];
            c= '0x'+c.join('');
            
            // Set the return value as an Object rather han an array
            return {
                r:( c>>16 )&255,
                g:( c>>8 )&255,
                b:c&255
            };
        }
        throw new Error('Bad Hex');
    };
    
    const GColor=(r,g,b)=>{
        // Not a constructor so do not call new GColor
        r = (typeof r === 'undefined')?0:r;
        g = (typeof g === 'undefined')?0:g;
        b = (typeof b === 'undefined')?0:b;
        return { r:r, g:g, b:b };   
    };
    
    const createColorRange=(c1,c2)=>{
        let colorList=[], tmp;
        for( let i=0; i < 255; i++ ) {
            tmp = GColor();
            tmp.r = c1.r + ( ( i * ( c2.r - c1.r ) ) / 255 );
            tmp.g = c1.g + ( ( i * ( c2.g - c1.g ) ) / 255 );
            tmp.b = c1.b + ( ( i * ( c2.b - c1.b ) ) / 255 );
            colorList.push( tmp );
        }
        return colorList.concat( colorList.slice().reverse() );
    };
    
    const rotateColors=()=>{
        let obj = range[ pointer ];
        div.style.backgroundColor = "rgb( "+obj.r+", "+obj.g+", "+obj.b+" )";
        pointer++;
        
        if( pointer === range.length )pointer=0;
        tx=window.setTimeout( rotateColors, 5 );
    };
    
    
    
    document.forms.colours.querySelector( '[type="submit"]' ).addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        if( !isNaN(tx) )clearTimeout(tx); //clear any timeouts that arerunning before starting another....
        const [ startColor, endColor ]=getColorValues( event );
        range=createColorRange( startColor, endColor );
        
        rotateColors();
    })
});
```

```css
body,body *{font-family:monospace;box-sizing:border-box;}
#test { width:100%; min-height:300px; border:solid 1px #000; margin: 2rem auto 0rem auto; float:none; }
form[name='colours']{float:none;margin:auto;width:50%;padding:1rem;border:1px solid black;}
label{display:block;margin:1rem auto;width:80%;float:none;}
label > input{float:right}
input[type='submit']{padding:1.5rem;width:100%}
```

```html
<form name='colours'>
  <label>Color One:<input type='color' name='color1' value='#fbafff' /></label>
  <label>Color Two:<input type='color' name='color2' value='#cc55ff' /></label>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
  <div id='test'></div>
</form>
```

Initially the form had `text` input elements - one of which was incorrectly defined

`<input type="text" id="color2" name"color2">` ~ requires an `equals` sign before the name - `<input type="text" id="color2" name="color2">` but as you were using the ID to identify the elements this was never flagged as an error. However, the ID for the label can be omitted if the input element lies within the label - which also serves the double purpose of facillitating the layout you achieved using the `br` tags - hence the ID was removed and the inputs located inside the labels. By changing the `text` to `color` inputs might yield problems with some browsers, most likely older Internet Exploder, but does guarantee valid colour codes!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function in code (must be called after user's actions like clicks), by the way that event handler must have event parameter:

```
elem.onclick = function eventHandler(event, yourParameters){}
```